# Inexpensive SMALL UPS circuit

Tags: power-supply

Thank you all guys for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate it. Now, I think I made a mistake and asked the question wrong. I know that I can use a telephone charger to power up a small sensor instead of batteries (I am using a laser with an LDR and a light-dependent motion sensor - it only works when it is dark). What I may need is a  switch (either with relay or with transistors) to swap between the domestic power supply and the batteries in case of a power shortage.
I apologize, maybe this forum is for advanced users and I am not one. I thank you all twice for that.

→I am trying to build an **inexpensive SMALL UPS circuit** allowing me to swap between domestic power line and batteries. It would be fine if it could convert from 110 or 220 VAC to 5 or 12 VDC. **Is this even possible without making a bulky device or using a transformer?**
Thanks a lot for your answer even if it is to tell me it is not possible.←

Comment: You're going to need a transformer regardless.  I'm not sure how you define small and bulky but chances are, no.  I wouldn't recommend you work with line voltages, since they are lethal, until you are fully aware of what you are working with.

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to add battery support to the DC side of your power supply, and it can work with your existing power supply.  You won't be able to get rid of the transformers you already use, but you won't have to add new ones or consider them in the design.

Comment: Thank you both Funkyguy and Ben Voigt. Yes, "bulky" is a relative term, but I mean "even smaller than" a 5V telephone charger. That is question #1. The most important part is though, how to automatically switch between power line and battery with no gap or virtually no gap. I can live with having to use transformers anyway. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer - what are you intending to run on this UPS, and for how long?  It might be worth checking if your intended use case is actually possible... a washing machine, for example, would require a very non-trivial battery to USP for any real amount of time,

In which case, I'd strongly recommend buying a real UPS.  Poking mains power is *dangerous*.

Comment: Hello user702772. I edited my question, but basically, I need to have a sensor to work uninterruptedly even if there's a power shortage, so I need it to be capable of using power from the domestic network and swap to batteries if needed. The UPS idea may not be exactly what I need, although there are similarities between an UPS and what I need. Thanx.

Comment: Simply put, I need a mechanism that allows to automatically switch between 5V power supply (from telephone charger) and 5V (supplied by batteries).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use AC to USB adapter and USB power bank (USB battery). Most USB power banks have a charge input and USB output, and when they are being charged, the same power is also supplied to output.

This will give you 5V which always works, no matter if you have domestic power or not.

Comment: Not all powerbanks allow to supply power while being charged, that must be investigated. Apart from that its an solution for small equipment

Answer (score 0):

Based on what kind of voltage your device requires to work the solution can be different.

- DC 3.3V: With a Schottky drop the Li-ion battery can be used directly. Couple it to a phone charger and a Li-ion battery charge/control/protection circuit you are good to go. (18650 cells, `TP4056`, `DW01A` and two MOSFETs)
- DC 5V: get one of those "battery banks" that can give your phone some extra juice. That will be sufficient, and for some models you don't even need a relay as the output switches between drawing energy from the wall wart and the batteries automatically.
- DC 12V, 24V or 48V: get a car battery rated for that voltage and corresponding charger. Same principal above applies
- Mains voltage: A transformer have to be used in this case. You can buy ready-made ones, or should you want to build one yourself, try this: use a microcontroller to generate PWM signals matching a sinusoidal wave, and drive a H-bridge with that, and use a transformer to output mains voltage.